# Google Web Designer aligning text for multiple mobile devices

Tags: android, css, iphone, html, google-web-designer

I built this banner ad, and when I open the disclaimer with my Galaxy phone the copy is off the box, it works fine on an iPhone, anyone familiar with similar issues?

http://creative.kmphdigital.com/larrymiller/Cherokee300x250/

Comment: I will make sure i specify the font on the disclaimer this evening. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you specify a webfont for the disclaimer text? If you don't specify a webfont, the OS/browser/device will default to a fallback system font.

For example, on my Linux desktop, the disclaimer text is displayed in Times New Roman on Chrome but in DejaVu Serif on Firefox. On Firefox, the text flows out of the text box.

On my Mac laptop, the text is displayed in Times on Chrome and Times Roman on Firefox and appears fine in both.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did that and it seems that it resolved my issues. Thanks again